# JFrame updates only upon resizing window

Tags: java, swing, repaint

I'm trying to make my own version of Snake for learning purposes. Everything seems to work fine except that if I want my frame to be repainted, I have to resize my window manually. Here is my code:

```
package snake;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class PlayGame extends JPanel implements Runnable{

    public boolean animate = false;           
    public final int FRAME_DELAY = 750;

    PickupBall b = new PickupBall();
    Snake bob = new Snake();


    public synchronized void start() {
        animate = true;
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        animate = false;
    }
    private synchronized boolean animationEnabled() {
        return animate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){            
        while(true){    
            if (animationEnabled()){                    
                repaint();                    
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(FRAME_DELAY);
            }   
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    }        

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){            
        super.paintComponent(g);  

        b.draw(g);
        bob.draw(g);            
    }        

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        JFrame jfr = new JFrame("Snake");  
        jfr.setSize(640,640);
        jfr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);            
        jfr.setResizable(true);

        PlayGame p = new PlayGame();  

        jfr.setContentPane(p);  

        p.setBackground(Color.WHITE);            

        p.start();            

        new Thread(p).start();            
        jfr.setVisible(true);    

    }


}
```

Why isn't repaint() triggered without altering the frame size? I get the correlation but it makes no sense to me why it needs such a trigger when it's in a while(true) loop anyway.

What am I missing here?

Edit 1:
Removed thread object
Replaced t.start() with p.start()

Edit 2:
Added `new Thread(p).start();` and now it works! Thanks.

Edit 3:
Removed `revalidate();`

Comment: PlayGame p = new PlayGame();
Thread t = new Thread(p);
t.start();

Comment: `t.start()`, but never `p.start()`, so `animate` is always `false`.

Comment: Alright, so does this mean the thread object is pointless?

Comment: Trying to run an animation loop in the [EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) would block it. I'd use a swing [Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) though.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Don't call `revalidate();` inside a paint method it has nothing to do with painting and could cause other side effects

Comment: Nothings calling `run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added `new Thread(p).start();`

Still have no idea how or why this is different to 
`Thread t = new Thread(p);`
`t.start();`

But it worked.

Comment: They are not different, the problem is not there. The problem was that you called `start` from the `Thread` class, but not the `start` from your `PlayGame` class. They are both entirely different methods and you need to call both. The `start` in `Playgame` could have any name you want, it was misleading that it had the same name as the method from `Thread`.

Answer (score 1):

You are executing `repaint()` in the worker thread and not in the *event dispatch tread (EDT)* which is the only one actually drawing onto the screen.

You have to en queue the call to `repaint()` in the EDT using `SwingUtilities` static methods `invokeLater()` or `invokeAndWait()`.

Comment: Could you show me? I have no idea where to put that, and google isn't helping.

Comment: `repaint` is thread safe, as it post the actual paint event onto the EDT to be processed